# supermarket change price

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table tr_p

```
id  date
01  2015-02-03
01  2015-03-12
02  2015-03-12
01  2015-03-13
02  2015-03-21
```

and table MR_P

```
id updatedate  price
01 2015-03-01  5000
01 2015-03-13  6000   
02 2015-03-12  4500
02 2015-03-18  5500
```

now i want to show:

```
id    date        price
01    2015-03-02  5000
01    2015-03-12  5000
01    2015-03-13  6000
02    2015-03-12  4500
02    2015-03-21  5500
```

price change when date past

Comment: Why tagged both: *MySQL* and *SQL-Server*? Also what you have tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far also can you explain your login behind this desired output???

Comment: so i want to show date from tr_p and price based update date, ex for id 1: 2015-03-02 price still 5000, when 2015-03-13 price change 6000

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you want the price last assigned to each ID.

Here are 2 ways of solving it, note this answer is written for sqlserver 2008+:

Test tables & data

```
DECLARE @tr_p table(id int, date date)
insert @tr_p
values
(01,'2015-03-03'),
(01,'2015-03-12'),
(02,'2015-03-12'),
(01,'2015-03-13'),
(02,'2015-03-21')

DECLARE @MR_P table
(id int, date date, Price int)
insert @MR_P values
(01,'2015-03-01','5000'),
(01,'2015-03-13','6000'),
(02,'2015-03-12','4500'),
(02,'2015-03-18','5500')
```

Outer apply approach:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, t1.Date, x.Price
FROM @tr_p t1
OUTER APPLY
( 
  SELECT top 1 Price FROM @MR_P t2 
  WHERE t1.date >= t2.date and t1.id = t2.id 
  ORDER BY  t2.date desc) x
ORDER BY t1.id, x.price
```

Subselect approach:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.Date, 
  (SELECT top 1 Price FROM @MR_P t2 
  WHERE t1.date >= t2.date and t1.id = t2.id 
  ORDER BY  t2.date desc) Price
FROM @tr_p t1
ORDER BY id, price
```

Result in both queries:

```
id  Date        Price
1   2015-03-03  5000
1   2015-03-12  5000
1   2015-03-13  6000
2   2015-03-12  4500
2   2015-03-21  5500
```

Comment: `OUTER APPLY` all the way not so much the sub-query in select , will be executed for each row returned by the outer query :) + 1

Comment: @M.Ali thanks for your input. The outer apply will also be executed for all rows, I am not 100 % sure, but I would think the subselect is slightly faster.

Comment: To my knowledge `APPLY` gets executed once and then the result set is compared and fed into the outer query's result set based on the where clause, A correlated sub-query in select is definitely execute once for each row returned by the outer query and then compared if there is matching row (based on where clause). APPLY works much like a join, have a read of this [`SQL Server CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

Comment: I read the article and see nothing about comparing apply with subselect. I did an extensive test on my database and it seemed the queries had exactly the same performance as the execution plan confirmed as well (with my local indexes). Maybe you were refering to apply vs join on a subselect.